# Does "make -j" always produce correct result?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When using "`make -j`" command to allow run multiple jobs in parallel, is it always safe? I mean "`make -j`" can cause compile error, when "`make`" is OK?

Comment: If the dependencies are not correctly set up, things can be made in the wrong order leading to build errors. Running `make` multiple times usually solves it. The best solution though is to refactor the dependencies and if that's not possible, then not running a parallel make to begin with.

Comment: Or put in a slightly different way: If `make -j` leads to errors, the `Makefile` is erroneous (typically missing some dependency information) and running it single-threaded just hides this error.

Comment: I work with an old gcc-based compiler (~1997) and building with -j2 or more causes errors, like if it wasn't thread-safe. Anyway this shouldn't happen anymore if you're using the newest version of your compiler.